# how to redirect UI application to access denied on every type of request in .net core

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have two application one is API and one is UI, in api some methods or permission based return as per below code

```
 if (!await _permissionMasterServcie.Authorize(StandardPermissionProvider.Category, PermissionType.View).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            return AccessDenied();
        }
```

then this consume in UI .net core application. In this application some method is call by jQuery or Kendoui grid, some MVC so when UI .net core application consume API its got status code "401 Unauthorized" so can we redirect every request in UI application to access denied page when status code received "401 Unauthorized". By any attribute or any configuration in startup file. I didn't get how to do that.

UI .net core application consuming api

```
public virtual async Task<IRestResponse> PostAsync(string request, string endPoint, string action, string token)
    {
        string url = endPoint + action;
        _restClient.BaseUrl = new Uri(url);
        _restRequest.Method = Method.POST;
        _restRequest.Timeout = 900000;
        _restRequest.Parameters.Clear();
        _restRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", token);
        _restRequest.AddParameter("application/json", request, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = await _restClient.ExecuteAsync(_restRequest, Method.POST);
        return response;
    }
```

here I'm getting response and status code both, here can we redirect every request to access denied for 401 code

Answer (score 0):

Since you have multiple client, there is no way to write a common solution to redirect the page after the you have received the 401 status codes.

You could only write the logic to check the status codes when you get the response, if you find the response status codes is 401, then you could redirect page to UI's 401 page.

In my opinion, the best solution is you could directly return a error page in your web api controller action.

Then you could write the logic to directly show the returned html response. Like below:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ContentResult Get()
    {
        return new ContentResult
        {
            ContentType = "text/html",
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
            Content = "<html><body>Access deniend</body></html>"
        };
    }
```

Then you could directly write the response to show the error message like below ajax does.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/MyTestAction',
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (response) {
        //do something
    },
    error: function (response) {
        //console.log(response);
        document.write(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: so every time i have to check  status code in Controller. This process im doing. this is not my question my simple questing is can be wrap the httpclient call or restsharp call and then get response in this pipeline and then redirect if got 401 otherwise not need to check condition

Comment: As far as I know, we couldn't capture the server send request and get response in middleware or else in asp.net core application. The only way we could do is we could return a whole error page in the web api and show the error page in the client side.